# Change only browser URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I spent some hours looking for an answer via google and on here and I can't seem to get this to work

This is my URL:
http://mysite.co.uk/joomla30/landing-page-register?&tmpl=component

I simply want the ?&tmple=component removed in the browser URL only as the query at the end needs to be there at the server end but the browser would show.

http://mysite.co.uk/joomla30/landing-page-register

I have tried about 20 ways of doing this but I cant seem to get it to work I currently have

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^landing-page-register$ /joomla30/landing-page-register?   &tmpl=component [L]
```

htaccess is enabled as I already use it change a few .php files and redirect incoming traffic from warez sites, I just cant get this to work.

Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /joomla30/landing-page-register\?\&tmpl=component
RewriteRule ^ /joomla30/landing-page-register? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^landing-page-register$ /joomla30/landing-page-register?&tmpl=component [L]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work it now throws up a 404 not found error, I had that before with a few other versions of it I tried.

Comment: @Paul I assume your htaccess file is in the `joonla30` directory?

Comment: Yes the joomla30 is a subdirectory I use as a dev site.

Comment: @paul and there's no other rules in the htaccess file?

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -Indexes